# Need advice on writing a document control software with Python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, file

I'm looking for open-ended advice on the best approach to re-write a simple document control app I developed, which is really just a custom file log generator that looks for and logs files that have a certain naming format and file location. E.g., we name all our Change Orders with the format "CO#3 brief description.docx". When they're issued, they get moved to an "issued" folder under another folder that has the project name. So, by logging the file and querying it's path, we can tell which project it's associated with and whether it's been issued.

I wrote it with Python 3.3. Works well, but the code's tough to support because I'm building the reports while walking the file structure, which can get pretty messy. I'm thinking it would be better to build a DB of most/all of the files first and then query the DB with SQL to build the reports.

Sorry for the open-ended question, but I'm hoping not to reinvent the wheel. Anyone have any advice as to going down this road? E.g., existing apps I should look at or bundles that might help? I have lots of C/C++ coding experience but am still new to Python and MySQL. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm still looking for some advice on creating my simple document control app described above. Effectively, I want to create a custom log for files that have a certain naming format and location.

Comment: Yikes, you chose .docx as a document type? `:-)`

Comment: Not my choice. Our industry (architecture/construction) primarily uses MS files and PDFs for text documentation.

Comment: @halfer we have all been there. Although people may be sending in DOC, DOCX..., consider something like antiword or headless LibreOffice to convert into something homogeneous (retain the originals if you want), you will be glad in the future :)

Comment: @Josep, that's a good solution to the problem, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really nice answer by @GCord. I'd add just two bits:

- If it's a relatively small database, consider sqlite3 instead of
  MySQL (it is nicely supported out of the box, multiplatform, no
  dependencies on a running rdbms)
- If it's expected to grow, and/or you
  just want to play with some new technology, try to write automated
  ingestion scripts for a real document management system (e.g., http://www.alfresco.com/). I'd
  recommend Apache Solr (based on Apache Lucene) as a full text
  indexing service and then you could use Apache Tika to automatically
  extract text and metadata from your documents (see
  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler)

Comment: Checked out sqlite3 and it looks perfect for my application. Thanks! Thanks too for the Apache recommendation. Unfortunately I don't have the time to invest in a whack of new tech, so sqlite it is.

Comment: @buttonsrtoys: SQLite is a very good solution. Note that it does support foreign keys, but you have to turn them on explicitly every time you connect - look up `PRAGMA`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if it works well as you suggest, then why fix it?

Secondly, before doing any changes to your code I would ask myself the following questions:

1. What are the improvements/new requirements I want to implement that I can't easily do with the current structure?
2. Do I have a test suite of the current solution, so that I can regression-test any refactoring? When re-implementing something it is easy to overlook some specific behaviors which are not very well documented but that you/users rely on.
3. Do those improvements warrant an SQL database? For instance:

   - Do you need to often run reports out of an SQL database without walking the directory structure?
   - Is there a problem with walking the directories?
   - Do you have network or performance issues?
   - Are you facing an increase in usage?
4. When implementing an SQL solution, you will need a new task to update the SQL data. If I understand correctly, the reports are currently generated on-the-fly, and therefore are always up-to-date. That won't be the case with SQL reports, so you need to make sure they are up-to-date too. How frequently will you update the SQL database:

   - a) In real-time? That will necessitate a background service. That could be a operational hassle.
   - b) On-demand? Then what would be the difference with the current solution?
   - c) At scheduled times? Then your data may be not up-to-date between the updates.

I don't have any packages or technical approaches to recommend to you, I just thought I'd give you those general software management advices.

In any case, I also have extensive C++ and Python and SQL experience, and I would just stick to Python on this one.

On the SQL side, why stick to traditional SQL engines? Why not MongoDB for instance, which would be well suited to storing structured data such as file information.

Comment: Thanks for thoughts. Regarding your comments:
1. As mentioned, the code is tough to support, e.g., add new functionality and follow it's logic in places, in part because of some deep nesting.
2. Yes, I have a test suite for regression testing. 3. Not strong in SQL, so not sure it's warranted. My current software is single-pass. A multi-pass approach would be possibly simpler to implement and more flexible, which is why I'm investigating SQL. 4. On-demand and at scheduled times adequate. Wasn't aware of MongeDB. Will check it out.